# Bash: Checking if can sudo on remote host using sshpass; how 'exposed' is the password?

Tags: networking, ssh, bash, password, sudo

I am using bash script below to test whether `sudo` is available on a remote host.

I'm obtaining the password from user input. I understand (to a limited extent) that using passwords inside a script will involve security trade-offs, so I have a question about a particular aspect of this.

Please see script below, which uses `sshpass` and then tests if the user is able to run `sudo --stdin --validate` successfully.

To mitigate exposing the password (as best as I know?) I've opted to use `sshpass` with `-e` instead of `-p`, but just wondering about the second part---the `echo \"${SSHPASS}\" | sudo --stdin --validate` line.

After running this script and then looking through `history` on the remote host, I could not see the password 'echoed' on the command line both in the user account or as root.

So my question is: Does echoing like this at the remote end expose the password anywhere (and if so, where?), or is this method below "fairly safe"?

User environment on both ends is Ubuntu 18 or 20.

```
#!/bin/bash

# obtain username and host from user input
read -p "Enter username@host: " remote

# obtain password from user input
read -r -s -p "Enter password: " SSHPASS

# set password as environment variable for `sshpass` below, it requires this for `-e`
export SSHPASS

echo
echo -n "Testing if can sudo on ${remote}... "

if result=$( sshpass -e ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=yes "${remote}" "echo \"${SSHPASS}\" | sudo --stdin --validate" 2>&1 ); then
    echo "YES!"
else
    echo "FAILED"
    echo "${result}"
fi

unset SSHPASS
```

Comment: Only thing I can think about is your environment variable. Couldn't you unset it inside the bash script? Do you see this variable when using "printenv" after script execution? For your concerns regarding echo command. I don't see it as a problem, since echo stdout is directly passed to stdin of sudo command. But generally speaking I would suggest you to think about using a configuration mangament software for this task.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I'll make that change. And regardless, no, I can't see the SSHPASS variable when running `printenv` on the remote host both as root and as normal user, and same on the local machine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it doesn't look like it, the password is actually exposed on the local and remote server.

The reason in both cases is that it is part of the command line of the processes, either `sshpass`or the more implicit `bash -c` as outlined below.

When you run a command via `ssh <host> <command>`, the *command* part is passed to the login shell via `-c`. This implies that any user that is able to list processes can see `bash -c "echo "<password>" | sudo --stdin --validate"`.

If you want to test it out, a simple `while ! ps aux | grep '[s]udo'; do :; done` as any other user in the remote system should work. Note that this is an active wait loop and will spike CPU usage.

To fix that, you should echo the password and pipe it to your SSH instead of having it echoed remotely: `echo "${SSHPASS}" | sshpass -e ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=yes "${remote}" "sudo --stdin --validate" 2>&1`.

Comment: `sshpass` seems to do some funky stuff with the tty, I'll look into it tomorrow. I assume you're on macOS, try `ps -A` instead of `ps aux`.

Comment: Edited the answer to fix the "testing it out". I just tested `echo passwd | sshpass -e ssh $host 'sudo --stdin --validate'` and it works for me on Ubuntu 20.04. What's your sshpass version? Can you try replacing `sudo --stdin --validate` with `hexdump -c` in both scenarios to compare?

Answer (score 1):

Limit exposure more with GPG encryption and PIPE the output directly rather than to a plain text file / string:

> gpg -d -q .sshpasswd.gpg | sshpass -P pass ssh -i ~/.ssh/key.pem -ttR xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

> -P pass

option searches for e.g a "password..." or "passphrase" prompt to fill.

Answer (score 0):

try to run sshpass at local (for remote sudo), but failed

### 1. test

sudo without ssh //ok

```
$ SSHPASS=your_passwd sshpass -e sudo id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

sudo with ssh //fail

```
SSHPASS=your_passwd sshpass -v -e  ssh localhost -t 'sudo id' 
[sudo] password for xxx:
```

### 2. reason

```
$ ssh root@localhost  >/dev/null
root@localhost's password:

$ sudo id >/dev/null
[sudo] password for xxx:
```

```
$ ssh -t localhost sudo id 
[sudo] password for xxx:

$ ssh -t localhost sudo id >/dev/null
//nothing
```

the reason 'sshpass' can't work via ssh + sudo is that:
normal `sudo` or `ssh` send prompt to tty, but `ssh` + `sudo`
send prompt to stdout, but sshpass wait prompt at tty.

I guess the topology like that:

```
[local pty]  <---> ssh <--(stdio)--> [remote pty] <---> sudo
```

### workaround

so `sudo --stdin` is the easy way: //echo at local for safe

```
echo your_pass | ssh localhost 'sudo --stdin id'
```

or //run sshpass at remote

```
$ ssh localhost 'SSHPASS=your_pass sshpass -e sudo id'
```

---

I remember that bash only record commands history that executed in interactive mode,
and cmd start with space also not record: `ls 1`(record) vs  `ls 2` (not record)